# What is the correct way to deploy a feature branch of an Angular app to GitHub Pages?

Tags: angular, github-pages, angular-cli-ghpages

I have made a number of changes to an Angular repo on a branch called feat/demo-mode and I want to publish this branch to GitHub Pages.

Under the GitHub Pages section, I chose my branch as outlined here [configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site).

I have added/updated the following scripts in package.json

```
"build": "ng build --prod --base-href /my-example-repo/",
"predeploy": "npm run build",
"deploy": "npx angular-cli-ghpages --dir=dist/my-example-repo --branch=feat/demo-mode --message='Deploy to GitHub Pages'"
```

When I run `npm run deploy`, the app builds and deploys. I can now visit it on `https://funfair-tech.github.io/my-example-repo/`, however the code in feat/demo-mode has now been replaced with the contents of my dist folder.

Answer (score 0):

So I updated my package scripts to this:

```
"build": "ng build --prod --base-href \"/funfair-client/\"",
"deploy": "npm run build && npx angular-cli-ghpages --dir dist/my-example-repo"
```

After I ran `npm run deploy` the first time, I went into GitHub Pages and changed the publishing source to gh-pages. Now when I make a change in the feature branch, I push the changes to git then run `npm run deploy` again.